# Setup VPN connection from Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: vpn, hyper-v

I have Windows 10 Pro x64 virtual machine running in Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro x64 host. I'm trying to create PPTP VPN from client VM, but I get following error:

> Remote Access error 800 - The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed. The VPN server might be unreachable. If this connection is attempting to use an L2TP/IPsec tunnel, the security parameters required for IPsec negotiation might not be configured properly.

When I try to create same VPN connection from host, it works without any problems.
Any ideas how to solve this?